# How to see php-fpm error log?

Tags: php, nginx, logging, centos7

My config:
CentOS 7, Nginx, php-fpm

I have Simple Machines Forum installed (SMF). I tried applying a minor update to the forum (SMF 2.0.13 --> SMF 2.0.14) that was supposed to self update on-the-fly with no issues. After the update I get

```
Connection Problems

Sorry, SMF was unable to connect to the database. This may be caused by the server being busy. Please try again later.
```

The folks at SMF aren't very helpful about it.

How can I see any logs from php-fpm so that I have any clue why the forum can't connect to the database?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific *problem* or *error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you checked the `nginx` error log? Any php errors sent to stderr may be recorded there.

Comment: Yes, I checked nginx error log. Nothing there, either.